# The Bartender's Dilemma

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

A bartender has 3 glasses. All of them are kept face down.
[image]
He needs to make all the three glasses face-up. **He is allowed to touch only two glasses at a time, no less no more, and he has to turn both the glasses he touches.**

How is it done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the key is

> stacking

So, labelling the cups A, B, and C:

> pick up A and C and put A over B and then C over the stack. Turn the stack without touching B. Take your hands away having touched and turned. Pick up B and then A from the stack, turn them over and set them down, having touched and turned. C remains, right way up. Pick up and turn A and B to make them also right way up.

Done.